# How to fix below file error while compress images by electron app using imagemin?

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, imagemin

I have created a basic image compression app using electron and imagemin which is working fine when running usin `npm start` command.

After that i packaged the app using electron packager and run the exe file and tried to compress the image again.

this time i got below error

```
Error: Error in file: path_to_image.jpg

write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:136)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:703)
    at Socket._write (net.js:715)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299)
    at Socket.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:584)
    at Socket.end (net.js:531)
    at handleInput (C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\slice\release-builds\slice-win32-ia32\resources\app.asar\node_modules\execa\index.js:87)`
```

here is the code below

```
const path = require('path')
const imagemin = require('imagemin');
const imageminMozjpeg = require('imagemin-mozjpeg');

const files = await imagemin(["path_to_image.jpg"], path.dirname(r) + '/optimized', {
        plugins: [
            imageminMozjpeg({
                quality: document.getElementById('jq').value
            })
        ]
    }).then(file => {
        console.log(file);
    })
    .catch(Error => console.log(Error));
```

Is there anything i am missing while packaging the app?

Comment: is it a public repo ? have a link ?

Comment: here https://github.com/tarami01/compressor01.git

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you ever solved this thing? would love a pointer...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I solve it by passing  false to asar (I use electron-builder) like this

```
"build": {
   "asar": false
 },
```

You can achieve the same thing with electron-packager by passing  `--no-asar` to the packaging script